# Improving a filter array function, to match elements and conditions

Tags: javascript, array

I have to do some check/match elements with conditions.
A have a list of conditions, each with a specific ID.
I've put for each of my elements an array with the ids of their respective affirmative conditions.

Some elements can share a condition. The goal is to, everytime a condition is "checked" by the user, the code filter the array with all elements, showing only the ones that attend the conditions.

I've made this function. But I don't know if its the "best" way..

this.selectedConditions is already maped by ID

Any help?

---

```
private filterElements(){

    let filtered: any[] = [];

    originalArray.forEach( item => {

      let isPossibility: boolean = true;

      for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedConditions.length; i++) {

        if( item.condition_matrix.indexOf( this.selectedConditions[i] ) === -1 ){
          isPossibility = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if( isPossibility ){
        filtered.push(item);
      }

    });

    this.outputArray = filtered;

    if(this.outputArray.length === 0){
      this.outputArray.push( { <a_filler_object> } );
    }
}
```

---

Elements list example:

```
elements: [
    {
        name: 'el1',
        condition_matrix: [1,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'el2',
        condition_matrix: [2,3]
    },
    {
        name: 'el3',
        condition_matrix: [2,1]
    }
]
```

Conditions list example:

```
conditions: [
    {
        id: 1
        name: 'cond1' 
    },
    {
        id: 2
        name: 'cond2' 
    },
    {
        id: 3
        name: 'cond3' 
    }
]
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting the code first and the example data after that. Looking at the example data makes the question look hypothetical, which is off-topic for code review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw edited. Thx buddy

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using TypeScript, so a couple pointers:

**Avoid `any`** - `any` effectively disables type-checking, which defeats the whole point of using TypeScript. Better to type variables properly:

```
let filtered: Array<{ name: string; condition_matrix: Array<number>; }> = [];
```

Or, even better, let TypeScript infer the types automatically when possible, by transforming the data *all at once* with array methods (see below). No need to denote types when TS can infer them automatically - eg `let isPossibility: boolean = true;` can be just `let isPossibility = true;`

**Avoid `let`, prefer `const`** - see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6), using `const` indicates that the variable will never be reassigned, which reduces cognitive overhead.

**Semantic array methods** While `for` loops *work*, they should only be used as a last resort, when other array methods aren't appropriate. Here, rather than `break`ing inside a `for` loop to check if an item passes a condition, it would be better to use `.some`. Also, rather than `.push`ing to an outer array based on the condition, use `.filter` instead:

```
this.outputArray = originalArray.filter(
  item => this.selectedConditions.some(
    condition => item.condition_matrix.includes(condition)
  )
);
```

(Better to use `.includes` than to use an `indexOf` check against 0)

Or:

**Time complexity** If performance is an issue and you have a lot of conditions, rather than iterating all of the conditions each time, consider constructing a Set of all of the `selectedConditions` first; `Set#has` is `O(1)`, which is an improvement over iterating over arrays with `O(n)`.

```
const allConditions = new Set(this.selectedConditions);
```

**Conditions list typo?** The data structure in your code is an array of objects, but you're using `item.condition_matrix.indexOf( this.selectedConditions[i] )`. Did you mean:

```
item.condition_matrix.indexOf( this.selectedConditions[i].id )
```

?

(If so, and you want to use the Set method, map to IDs first:

```
const allConditions = new Set(
  this.selectedConditions.map(({ id ]) => id)
);
```

)

**Side-effects?** The result of the whole function is to *set* a value (to `this.outputArray`). Is this required? Code is generally easiest to understand and reason about when it does not contain side-effects. Imagine seeing some code you haven't looked at before, and compare:

```
this.calculate();
console.log('Result:', this.result);
```

vs

```
console.log('Result:', this.calculate());
```

The second is easier to make sense of because the method is used for its *return value* instead of for its side-effects (which, to understand, you'd have to read through the method to find).

Could your `filterElements` method return a value instead of assigning to `this.outputArray`?